# 1-out-of-2 OT from Random 1-out-of-2 OT

Tags: oblivious-transfer

Last week I came upon this problem in my h.w.:

> Let $OT^m$ denote 1-out-of-2 oblivious transfer of $m$ bit inputs.
>
> Let $RandOT^m$ denote the following primitive:
>
> 1. The sender’s input consists of two m-bit strings, $x_0, x_1$.
> 2. The receiver has no input.
> 3. At the end of the protocol the receiver learns $(b,x_b)$, for a randomly chosen $b$ in $\{0,1\}$, and learns nothing about $x_{1-b}$. The sender learns nothing. (Note that $b$ must be chosen at random, and neither nor the server should be able to choose the value of $b$).
>
> Show the following two reductions, for the semi-honest case.
>
> 1. It is possible to construct $RandOT^1$ from $OT^2$.
> 2. It is possible to construct $OT^1$ from $RandOT^1$.

I solved the first problem quite easily, but I just can't figure a way to solve the second one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad ​ ​

Comment: I can't see how the One-Time-Pad helps here :(

Comment: key length ​ = ​ message length ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Still I don't get it...

Comment: In particular, anything that can transfer a message, can instead be used to transfer a key. ​ ​

Comment: Could you please describe the protocol? I feel like I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 4):

We construct $OT^1$ from $RandOT^1$ as follows. Say, the Sender (S) has messages $m_0, m_1$ and the Receiver (R) has choice bit $c$. I.e., R needs to learn $m_c$. Now we first run the random OT. S now has random $x_0, x_1$ and R has $x_b,b$. The idea is now for S to somehow OTP $m_c$ with $x_b$ and $m_{c \oplus 1}$ with $x_{b \oplus 1}$ and send these values to R.

To do this R sends $d = b \oplus c$ to S (note this hides c as a OTP). S then sends $(y_0, y_1) = (x_{d} \oplus m_0, x_{d \oplus 1} \oplus m_1)$ to R. Note that we can write $y_i = x_{d \oplus i} \oplus m_i$. R then finds $m_c = y_c \oplus x_b$. Note, $y_c = y_{d \oplus b} = x_{d \oplus d \oplus b} \oplus m_c = x_b \oplus m_c$, thus we get the correct result. Also note, R does not learn $m_{c \oplus 1}$ as it is OTP'ed with $x_{b \oplus 1}$.

Comment: This is a classical trick originally due to Donald Beaver, "[Precomputing oblivious transfer](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-44750-4_8)", in Crypto 1995 (Fig 3).

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question and found it interesting.  Since no one has posted an answer, I wanted to maybe help get the ball rolling by throwing my ideas out there.  This is not an answer.

1. Sender generates random 1-bit keys $K_0, K_1$ and inputs them into $OT^1$.
2. Receiver reports to the sender whether or not he received the "correct" key ($K_0$ if he wants to receive message 0, $K_1$ if he wants to receive message 1).
3. If no, go back to 1.
4. If yes, the sender encrypts both the messages and sends the ciphertexts to the receiver.  $C_i = x_i \oplus K_i$ for $i \in \{0, 1\}$.
5. The receiver decrypts the desired message: $x_s = C_s \oplus K_s$ where $s \in \{0, 1\}$ is the receiver's selection input.

The receiver cannot learn anything about the nonselected string because $K_0$ and $K_1$ are independently selected.

There is no guarantee this algorithm will halt in a finite amount of time.